# Can i ran romex on top/side of top plate in finished basement?

Tags: electrical, basement, emt

My basement is finished and wonder if i can run romex on top or side of the top plate framing instead of through studs? Does it has to be protected?

Comment: It needs protection in places expected that people will drive nails/screws in.  This sounds like one of the uses for the top or side of a top plate.  The code people usually want an inch and a half of wood or steel plates/conduit.

Comment: If the cable is more than 8' above the floor then no, it doesn't have to be in conduit to protect it. Above that, it should be pretty obvious that an electrical cable is there, so if someone were to climb up and drive a nail/screw through a surface-mounted cable, it would have to be pretty intentional.

Comment: I mean, aside from having a finished basement and running bare wire on the wall.  I'd at least put it in a raceway of some sort.  Unfinished basement, different answer.